# Motorola Razr i (XT890) Apps

Tags: android, intel

I was thinking about buying a Motorola Razr i, with Intel Atom 2.0GHz.

My question is: I want to start studying Android Development, and the two Developers IDE I would use is native Java + Android SDK on Eclipse and Appcelerator.

Developing for Android with those IDEs I would have problems running my apps on Razr i, because it has an Intel processor. Or those "Intel apps problems" are only for Games and other kinda of apps which has instructions directly to some ARM Processors?

Many thanks!

:)

Comment: You only run into issues when you use NDK, with C++ doing native development that's when you need to specifically compile for x86 to run on your Razr i.  You shouldn't run into any issues if you code in Java Using Android SDK.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. So, and what about if I use Appcelerator Titanium instead of Java + Android SDK is the same thing, only if I have C++ Code (which is not Titanium case)? Thank you again!

Comment: As long as it's not C++, you should be fine.